# ModPagespeedLoadFromFile causing internal server error

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, apache2, mod-pagespeed

To enable SSL and use mod_pagespeed, you need to tell the mod, how to retrieve the resources. The way I need to work is using

```
ModPagespeedLoadFromFile "https://www.example.com" "/var/www/example/static/"
```

When I add this to my .htacces (with the correct url/directory), an internal server error occurs. Sadly no error is logged.

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Jul 22 2014 14:35:35

X-Mod-Pagespeed:1.9.32.1-4238
```

Is there anything that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directive may not be set in the .htaccess file. In the documentation it says so for other directives, but not the ModPagespeedLoadFromFile. It still applies here, you need to place it in your vhost configuration.